# Can SQL Server 2008 Scale Horizontally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read that SQL Server cannot scale horizontally. is this true?

I am planning a high traffic website and looking a for a database that can scale out easily across multiple servers.

Comment: Really need more details as to what you're trying to learn....I mean sharding and clustering abilities on SQL Server are very primitive at best, but we need more information to give a detailed answer.

Comment: You can use sharding. But don't kid yourself, SqlServer is not really designed to scale-out. You can take a look here : http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/When-up-isnt-enough-Techniques-for-scaling-SQL-Server-out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not true.
SQL server can [scale horizontally](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/two-options-for-scaling-out-your-sql-server-system/6170401), using [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

More recently, SQL 2012 has more options for horizontal scaling.

http://robtiffany.com/building-microsoft-meap-scaling-out-sql-server/

Answer (score -1):

Last week I heard about [partitiondb](http://www.partitiondb.com/), it really helped me. you just need to create one database that controls all partition databases and it manages them wonderfully. All you need is to declare your partitionid.

for example if your website is dealing with sales, you can partition your databases by storeid. then each store resides in different database instances or on a different server. all of them are managed from one template db, this gives the feeling of some sort of object oriented modelling.